# Type SFINAE in VS2015 compiles, but generates error

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015, sfinae

I have made two test classes:

```
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1(int a) {}
};

class Class2
{
public:
    Class2() {}
};
```

And two template functions using type SFINAE to decide which to use. The second one will "fail" if T is not default constructible.

```
template<typename T>
T* CreateInstanceTest(char*[!std::is_default_constructible<T>::value] = 0) { return nullptr; }

template<typename T>
T* CreateInstanceTest(char*[std::is_default_constructible<T>::value] = 0) { return new T(); }
```

Then I do this:

```
Class1* obj1 = CreateInstanceTest<Class1>();
Class2* obj2 = CreateInstanceTest<Class2>();
```

Which generates the error "more than one instance of overloaded function "CreateInstanceTest" matches the argument list".

However, it compiles fine and works as expected. obj1 becomes null and obj2 is created properly.

Why does this happen? And is there some way to get around it?

Comment: It generates an error, but compiles fine?

Comment: Yes. The text becomes red and I see an error in the "error list", but it builds fine and I can run the program. It also works as expected.

Comment: use `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: It is an Intellisense error, not a build error.

Comment: Why does intellisense generate an error, when the code is valid and works? Is it a bug?

Comment: Here is a similar example fro cppreference.com: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae#Type_SFINAE

Comment: @MyNiceDisplayName parsing the template code on the fly isn't as obvious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an Intellisense error, not a build error. Intellisense is not perfect, however as a workaround you can improve deduction code:

```
template<typename T> typename ::std::enable_if_t
<
    !::std::is_default_constructible<T>::value
,   T *
>
CreateInstanceTest(void) { return nullptr; }

template<typename T> typename ::std::enable_if_t
<
    ::std::is_default_constructible<T>::value
,   T *
>
CreateInstanceTest(void) { return new T(); }
```

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed not generate any errors.
It also looks like a nicer way to do what I wanted.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `::std` instead of just `std`? I don't think that someone uses `std` as their own identifier.

Comment: @Zereges Actually it does happen sometimes. For example people bring something into `std` namespace but mess up scoping and spawn nested `std` namespace instead of root one. It is always better to be on the safe side and since use of leading `::` does not have any pitfalls I tend to use it always.